# Automate the JMS Adapter properties in BizTalk

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am trying to automate the BizTalk application deployment and achieved  most of the task like host, host instance and handler creation using PowerShell scripts. But I have some JMS Adapters for which I need to update properties similar to shown in the below image.  Is there any option by which I can automate the configuration of JMS Adapter properties? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't verify the JNBridge Adapters fully support this (meaning you'll just have to try), yes.

You can follow this sample to set the Handler Properties: [Set Send Handler Property (BizTalk Server Sample)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/set-send-handler-property-biztalk-server-sample)

You will first have to export the Xml blob from this WMI Class: [MSBTS_SendHandler.CustomCfg Property (WMI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/technical-reference/msbts-sendhandler-customcfg-property-wmi)